# How to display less elements than there is in an array

Tags: c, arrays

I am making a program to separate even and odd integers from an array. I gave the even and odd arrays 3 elements but when there aren't 3 even/odd integers it prints out some random numbers. Is there any way to define what to print out. Here is the code if needed:

P.S. I found the solution to the problem but it has different approach,so i just want to know i it could have been done this way and if not, why? Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
     int nubmers[3];
     int even[3];
     int odd[3];

     for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
     {
         printf("Enter %d element : ", i);
         scanf(" %d", &numbers[i]);

         if(numbers[0]%2 == 0)
         {
             even[0] = numbers[0];
         }
         else
         {
             odd[0] = numbers[0];
         }

         if(nubmers[1]%2 == 0)
         {
             even[1] = numbers[1];
         }
         else
         {
             odd[1] = numbers[1];
         }

         if(numbers[2]%2 == 0)
         {
             even[2] = numbers[2];
         }
         else
         {
             odd[2] = numbers[2];
         }
     }

     printf("Even : %d\n", even[i]);
     printf("Odd : %d\n", odd[i]);

     return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's now how you use loops. Hint: You are filling `even` and `odd` three times instead of one.

Comment: yes i have corrected that in code but not in question thanks

Comment: @CinCout sorry i dont quite understand your comment what do i need to do make one if statement with even and else with odd or

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the loop you should use the loop counter variable `i` and not the fixed indices `0`, `1` and `2`.

Further you shuld count the number of even and the number of odd values.

Finally you can print a list of the even values and a list of the odd values.

```
int main()
{
     int nubmers[3];
     int even[3];
     int odd[3];
     int noEven = 0, noOdd = 0;

     for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
     {
         printf("Enter %d element : ", i);
         scanf(" %d", &numbers[i]);

         if (numbers[i]%2 == 0)
             even[noEven++] = numbers[i];
         else
             odd[noOdd++] = numbers[i];
     }

    for(int i = 0; i < noEven; i++)
        printf("Even : %d\n", even[i]);
    for(int i = 0; i < noOdd; i++)
        printf("Odd : %d\n", odd[i]);

     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice. Why not make it even nicer by wrapping the even-/odd-counter and the related array into a `struct` each and with this make it even nicer? ;)

Answer (score 1):

> How to display less elements than there is in an array

Define any "Not-In-Use" value and initialise the arrays with this.

A "Not-In-Use" value should be any value you definitely know that it would not be needed/used during the program's run.

In your case you could for example take the smallest `int` possible, which is defined as `INT_MIN`.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <limits.h> /* for INT_MIN */

#define NOT_IN_USE INT_MIN


int main(void)
{
  ...

  for (size_t i = 0; i < 3;: ++i)
  {
    numbers[i] = NOT_IN_USE;
    even[i] = NOT_IN_USE;
    odd[i] = NOT_IN_USE;
  }
```

Make sure the "Not-In-Use" value definitely isn't used:

```
  /* core program code here */
 for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
 {
   printf("Enter %d element : ", i);
   scanf(" %d", &numbers[i]);
   if (NOT_IN_USE == numbers[i]) 
   {
     printf("Invalid input. Try again.\n");
     --i;
     continue;
   }
```

If you then later want to inspect only those elements which had been used/touched just loop over the array's skipping all elements equal to the "Not-In-Use" value.

```
  /* Show results */
  for (size_t i = 0; i < 3;: ++i)
  {
    if (NOT_IN_USE != numbers[i])
    {
      printf("number[%zu] = %d\n", i, number[i]);
    }

    if (NOT_IN_USE != even[i])
    {
      printf("even[%zu] = %d\n", i, even[i]);
    }

    if (NOT_IN_USE != odd[i])
    {
      printf("odd[%zu] = %d\n", i, odd[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: out of curiosity, why are you using `<>` for `!=` ?

Comment: Wuah ... -  did too much Pascal lately ...  - fixed  :}

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: To be honest it wasn't Pascal but VBA ... ;}

Comment: I think Pascal uses `/=`. VBA like all BASIC flavours (and python 2) use `<>` that's sooo 80s :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Pascal, Delphi in fact [is `<>` as well](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/ref/refse103.html). "*sooo 80s*" haha "*retrocoding*"? ;-)

Comment: I'm glad you enjoyed my comment. I also enjoy retrocoding, but only in assembly :) BTW `/=` is for Ada, which looks (slightly) like Pascal.